# T- SQL / Find total time pending with multiple over lapping pend tasks / Need to ignore overlap and weekend days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duration

I am hoping for some help in removing weekends from this query. I have cases that have multiple pend tasks that can overlap in time. This query works, but I was hoping to remove weekends.

```
DECLARE @pends table (id varchar(50), d1 datetime, d2 datetime);

INSERT @pends
--- Play below me --- This is the query that pulls the pend tasks.
    SELECT
        dc.fldReferenceNumber,
        dt.fldCreatedTime,
        dt.fldDoneDate
    FROM ([Centerpoint_Reporting_Prod].[dbo].[dim_case] dc
    INNER JOIN ([Centerpoint_Reporting_Prod].[dbo].[dim_task] dt
    INNER JOIN ([Centerpoint_Reporting_Prod].[dbo].[fact_task] ft
    INNER JOIN [Centerpoint_Reporting_Prod].[dbo].[dim_task_type] dtt
        ON ft.fldTaskTypeIdTaskTypeKey = dtt.TaskTypeSK)
        ON ft.TaskSK = dt.TaskSK)
        ON ft.CaseKey = dc.CaseSK)
    WHERE dtt.Name_enUS LIKE 'Pending%' AND dt.fldDoneDate <> 0 and dc.fldReferenceNumber = 'CDCR-4998513'

--- Play above me ---
SELECT id, SUM (n) AS hold_days
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT
       t1.id,
       t1.d1 AS date,
       -DATEDIFF(DAY, (SELECT MIN(d1) FROM @pends), t1.d1)  AS n
   FROM @pends t1
   LEFT JOIN @pends t2
      ON t2.ID = t1.ID
      AND t2.d1 <> t1.d1
      AND t1.d1 BETWEEN t2.d1 AND t2.d2
   GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.d1, t1.d2
   HAVING COUNT(t2.ID) = 0
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DISTINCT
       t1.id,
       t1.d2 AS date,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, (SELECT MIN(d1) FROM @pends), t1.d2) AS n
   FROM @pends t1
   LEFT JOIN @pends t2
      ON t2.ID = t1.ID
      AND t2.d2 <> t1.d2
      AND t1.d2 BETWEEN t2.d1 AND t2.d2
   GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.d1, t1.d2
   HAVING COUNT(t2.ID) = 0
) s
GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into DATENAME in bol, there is also a function that returns the day of the week 1-7 where 1 is sunday and 7 is saturday.

```
DATENAME ( datepart , date )
```